# D3: use transition .attr('x') to horizontally slide <text> elements

Tags: d3.js, transition, slide

I want to

1. display some text one after another
2. after each of the text is displayed, I would like to slide them horizontally from the left side of the page to the right side of the page: so I would like to change the texts' x= 10 to x= 500.

I am able to make step 1) but not 2). 
Here is my script:

```
var textall =["one", "two", "three"]
  var number = -1
    d3.select('svg')
        .transition()
            .duration(0)
            .delay(0)
            .on("start", function addtext() {
            number+=1;
            if (number < textall.length){
                d3.select('svg').append('g').append("text")
                    .attr("class", "one")
                    .attr('x', 10)
                    .attr('y', function(d,i) {return (number+1)*30; })
                    .text(textall[number])
                    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                    .attr("font-size", "20px")
                    .attr("fill", "black")
                    .transition()
                        .duration(0)
                        .delay(2000)
                        .on("start", addtext);
                        }
            <!-- }; -->
        });

    d3.selectAll(".one")
        .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .delay(6000)
            .attr('x', 90)
```

On [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L52npbbx/4/)

Comment: Could you precise what you would like to happen during step 2?

Comment: @XavierGuihot, I have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcc0nz4n/) I have updated your fiddle, not with the end result but with enough that you can fill in the exact values. Basically I added and `.on("end")` function that moves the text after they have been added. Further tweaking can happen to improve the aesthetic.

Comment: Thanks @pmkroeker! I don't understand why I need to make the callback to  moveText twice  (cf lin 31 and 35). I commented either one to try to understand but I don't get it. If I comment out line 35 then only the first text is "slided", if I remove the second one, the all the texts are "slided" but text 1 and text 2 are slided together. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @Enora I think it has to do with how you are adding the elements but I'm not too sure. [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eft8t0L5/) I updated it again to hopefully provide a bit of clarity. d3 is very order driven so the order things are done might be a reason.